# CmdLine task for Syswow64

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement to run my .cmd and .bat file based build system using syswow64 since they perform 32 bit product builds. My question is how can I use the azure devops platform prebuilt tasks for this purpose so that instead of the 64 bit cmd, syswow\cmd.exe is used as the primary shell. I do not want to invoke the 32 bit shell from the 64 bit shell due to some other constraints.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to invoke the 32 bit shell from the 64 bit shell due to
>   some other constraints.

If so, another workaround I can think of is to use private agent to run the pipeline. Then in the system environment variable, change the path of cmd.exe and call cmd.exe from the Syswow64 folder.

[image]

If you use a hosted agent, there should be no other way to run cmd.exe for Syswow64 . The system environment variables of the hosted agent cannot be modified.